# ES6 access functions from child class

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

Given the codes below, how do I access the `bar()` from an the `Parent` class?

```
class Parent{
    constructor(){

    }

    foo(){
        this.bar() // not defined
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    bar(){

    }
}
```

Comment: `Parent` class does not know anything about `Child` that extends it.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin but that's... sad. Anyways thank you :)

Comment: and it's worth mentioning that child knows all about parent

Comment: But it's weird to extend the child instead xD haha. @MarkoMackic

Answer (score 0):

You do access it exactly as you did, but for it to be actually defined on `this` you have to create a `Child` instance not a `Parent` one:

```
var c = new Child();
c.bar() // works
c.foo() // calls c.bar() as well
```

Comment: Well yes that makes sense, I think my question is wrong, sorry. The exact use case that I need is use it inside the `Parent` class. I updated the question sorry again.

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx: If you need `bar` in `Parent` instances, then you should declare the method in the `Parent` class. While it is possible to directly refer to `Child.prototype.bar`, its usage in `Parent` would be against all good practices and design principles.